# ¿Cómo hacer push a un array que está dentro de un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Trato de introducir valores a un arreglo que se encuentra dentro de un objeto.

```js
let objeto = {
     nombre: "",
     valor: []
}
objeto.valor.push("2")
console.log(objeto.valor)
```

al hacer ejecutar el código del push me dice que el push es una función que no está definida ¿cómo puedo agregar ese valor al array que esta dentro de ese objeto?

Comment: Bueno.... aquí si funciona

Comment: Yo corro tu codigo y me funciona, debes de extender tu pregunta para poderte ayudar. Talvez sea por la versión de JS que usas

Comment: ¿Versión de JS? Hmmmm...

Comment: @padaleiana Sii yo tampoco creo, pero pues el código funciona, no tiene el problema que dice

Comment: A lo que voy es que técnicamente hacés referencia a la versión de _ES_, no de _JS_ :) Pero de que funciona acá, funciona.

Comment: podria ser que en tu codigo tengas el valor definido como null o undefined y eso te disparara el error.

Comment: @mariovzc resultamente tenía el valor en undefined pero requería que fuese así porque necesitaba cambiar el tipo de dato de la propiedad valor, cambié el undefined por el null y funcionó normal

Answer (score 0):

Si estás trabajando en un contexto donde `valor` podría no ser un array en algunos casos, entonces conviene que verifiques antes de intentar el `push`.

Una posibilidad sería advertir al usuario mediante un mensaje de que no es un array, por ejemplo:

```js
let objeto = {
  nombre: "",
  valor: null
}
if (objeto.valor instanceof Array) {
  objeto.valor.push("2")
  console.log(objeto.valor)
} else {
  console.log('No es un array');
}
```

O, se podría inicializar `valor` como array con el dato, por ejemplo:

```js
let objeto = {
  nombre: "",
  valor: undefined
}
let theNumber = 2;
if (objeto.valor instanceof Array) {
  objeto.valor.push(theNumber)
} else {
  objeto.valor = [theNumber];
}
console.log(objeto.valor)
```